# How can I know which direction the user swiped?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js, dragendjs

I use this plugin called Dragend https://github.com/Stereobit/dragend to have a touch-function. I think this uses some code of Hammertime, if you know this plugin more than Dragend.

There are Options like `onDrag` or `onSwipeStart` and `onSwipeEnd` to determine what happens on these events.

However I just can't figure out how to see in which direction I just swiped. Even if you dont know this plugin, I hope someone could help me out. Maybe with some JQuery to check the HTML/CSS changes that were made during/after swiping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the plugin http://stereobit.github.io/dragend/demos/simple/. The swipe is happening by modified the transform value. If we take some part of html from the example code from the plugin demo page.

```
<div id="swipeWrapper" style="overflow: hidden; width: 2500px; box-sizing: content-box; backface-visibility: hidden; perspective: 1000px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; transform: translateX(-500px);"></div>
```

Let us add an id for the wrapping div for illustration purpose and call it swipeWrapper.
In your javascript file. Read the transform value from the div.

```
var prevTransformValue = 0;//Initialize the value before you swipe; 
var swipeWrapper = document.getElementById('swipeWrapper');
var transformValue = swipeWrapper.style.transform;
var currentTransformValue =  transformValue.replace(/[^\d|^\-]/g,'');
```

The transformValue from the example is "translateX(-500px)";
 currentTransformValue = "-500";

Now compare  prevTransformValue > currentTransformValue the swipe direction is left and prevTransformValue < currentTransformValueswipe swipe direction is right.

Note: don't forget to set prevTransformValue = currentTransformValue; after you get the direction value. This example is if you are swiping in horizontal direction.

Comment: Great, thank you! I did it with JQuery for everyone interested: `transformBefore = parseInt($('#swipeWrapper').css('transform').split(',')[4]); `